# Sorting the output of "find -print0" by piping to the "sort" command

Tags: shell, find, sort, xargs

I need to be able to alphabetically sort the output of `find` before piping it to a command. Entering `| sort |` between didn't work, so what could I do?

```
find folder1 folder2 -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 myCommand
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use `find` as usual and delimit your lines with NUL. GNU `sort` can handle these with the -z switch:

```
find . -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 yourcommand
```

Comment: It does not seem to work with `find . -name '*.dat' -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -z | xargs -r0  > output.txt`. Is my line wrong due to the printf?

Comment: @Ben you're not using -print0 and are introducing newlines instead of NULLs.

Comment: or together with formating the output `find . -printf "%y %p \n\0" | sort -z`

Answer (score 68):

Some versions of `sort` have a `-z` option, which allows for null-terminated records.

```
find folder1 folder2 -name "*.txt" -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 myCommand
```

Additionally, you could also write a high-level script to do it:

```
find folder1 folder2 -name "*.txt" -print0 | python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("\0".join(sorted(sys.stdin.read().split("\0"))))' | xargs -r0 myCommand
```

Add the `-r` option to `xargs` to make sure that `myCommand` is called with an argument.

Comment: Good one (two?)... Interestingly, though, the two methods handle `.` differently... With `sort` it winds up at the end of the list... with `python` it sorts to the top.  (maybe python sorts with `LC_COLLATE=C`)

Comment: There is also the `-t \0` option for sort (which is a `-z` synonym)

Comment: The problem with all these `|sort` solutions is that you cannot use `-exec` any longer. OK, although it is possible to rewrite your statement given to `-exec` so that it works with `xargs`, the question is, __what about "mini-scripts"__? (`sh -c ...`) I wouldn't call that trivial to transform a 'sh -c' mini-script with *multiple* commands so that it can work with `xargs` (if possible at all, that is)

Comment: @syntaxerror: What problem do you have using sh -c with xargs? `printf %s\\n a b c d e | xargs -n3 sh -c 'printf %s, "$@"; printf \\n' x`

Comment: `-t \0` is not the same as `-z`. `-t` is for field separator, not for line delimiter.

Answer (score 10):

I think you need the `-n` flag for sort#

According to man sort:

```
-n, --numeric-sort
    compare according to string numerical value
```

**edit**

The print0 may have something to do with this, I just tested this. Take the print0 out, you can null terminate the string in sort using the `-z` flag

Comment: Well, that `print0` appears to be space-separating the filenames which is what I need to pass to my command, unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
find folder1 folder2 -name "*.txt" -print | 
  sort |
  parallel myCommand
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Comment: What is the justification for using GNU Parallel? To speed it up?

Comment: That and you do not need to mess with \0 separated records.

Comment: I don't understand that last statement. I create a file with a line break in the file name and execute your command: `cd /tmp && touch $'a\nz' && ls && find -maxdepth 1 -print | sort | parallel echo`. Total false output. I know GNU Parallel now, but that answer misses the original question, doesn't it?

Comment: I know that it is bad practice to use crazy characters in file names - I am already including the blank space. I just see that parallel has a -0 parameter. Nice. No downvote. `find -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort -z | parallel -0 echo`.

Comment: @uav In my 25 years of sysadmin I have never seen a user making a file with \n. I *have* seen plenty of files with ' space and ". So unless you have evil users or a filesystem with error, I will reckon you will not meet a file with \n that was not made by a fellow sysadm.

Comment: The original question was about print0. print0 used as separator \0 instead of line breaks. Why does print0 exist? I think in order to have a safe separator and thus be able to handle all the crazy characters. I know you know that. `\n` was just an example. You answer with print. Kinda missed the point. The main thing is to advertise. By the way: `echo 'will cite' | parallel --citation 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null`. To get rid of that annoying citation message.

Comment: @OleTange You will find \n being used by those trying to achieve command injection to defeat security measures.

Answer (score 5):

Some implementation of `find` supports ordered traversal directly via the `-s` parameter:

```bsh
$ find -s . -name '*.json'
```

From the FreeBSD find [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)):

```
-s       Cause find to traverse the file hierarchies in lexicographical
         order, i.e., alphabetical order within each directory.  Note:
         `find -s' and `find | sort' may give different results.
```

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions here don't work correctly because the `sort` command takes the full "path" string to sorting instead of the **filename** string.

This is a quite complicated but working example of **natural sorting results of the "find" command**:

```bsh
find every_minute -type f -name "*.sh" -printf '%f\t%p\n' | sort -V -k1 | cut -d$'\t' -f2 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -r0 -I {} echo 'Found: "{}"'
```

Result:

```
Found: "every_minute/api/1_build_synonyms.sh"
Found: "every_minute/search_module/2_rotate_index.sh"
Found: "every_minute/api/3_check_synonyms.sh"
Found: "every_minute/api/4_run_schedule.sh"
Found: "every_minute/search_module/10_test.sh"
```

Example of an invalid `find every_minute -type f -name "*.sh" | sort -z | xargs -r0 echo` command result:

```
every_minute/api/1_build_synonyms.sh
every_minute/api/3_check_synonyms.sh
every_minute/api/4_run_schedule.sh
every_minute/search_module/10_test.sh
every_minute/search_module/2_rotate_index.sh
```

*Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48385358/10452175) answer.*